# Polar coordinates in taxicab geometry

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, analytic-geometry

We know that in euclidean $\mathbb{R}^2$ space polar coordinates are defined by
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
$$\theta = \arctan\frac{y}{x}\text{.}$$
Now, geometrically we can think of it as of point, which is located somewhere in a distance $r$ from origin under angle $\theta$. Applying this logic to different metrics (taxicab for example) will definition of polar coordinates look like this
$$r = |x| + |y|$$
$$\theta = \arctan\frac{y}{x}\text{?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no commonplace generalization of polar coordinates to non-Euclidean metrics.

If I was to define one, I might use the fact that the angle is proportional to the curvilinear abscissa along the iso-$r$ curves (circles in the corresponding geometry).

In the case of the taxicab distance, these curves are tilted squares (diamonds) of diagonal $r$ (and side $r/\sqrt2$), and in the first quadrant the curvilinear abscissa from the $x$ axis is just $\sqrt2y$, ranging in $[0,\sqrt2r]$.

Hence, per quadrants, $\theta=$

$$\sqrt2\dfrac yr,\\
\sqrt2(1-\frac xr),\\
\sqrt2(2-\frac yr),\\
\sqrt2(3+\frac xr).$$

The "sine" and "cosine" functions would be triangular waves, with period $4\sqrt2$.

---

These formulas were obtained by using the Euclidean metric to measure the curvilinear abscissa. It seems more coherent to use the taxicab metric, resulting in the factor $\sqrt 2$ being replaced by $2$.

Comment: Thanks! And if I would like to do something like this in Chebyshev distance ($\max\{|x|, |y|\}$), where circle is square, how will sine/cosine function would like?

Comment: Square waves then.

Comment: In that case then, $sin_{max}(x) \approx sgn\left(\sin(x)\right)$?

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity: there is a scale factor.